# How to add a custom svg as the line/tooltip for recharts

Tags: reactjs, charts, recharts

I have a line chart with two lines.

For one of the lines, I want to use a custom svg to represent it in the chart. See screenshot.

How can I do this?

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<LineChart
   // width={800}
   onClick={() => {}}
   height={300}
   data={this.state.data}
   // margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
 >
   <XAxis dataKey="to_char" />
   <YAxis
      tickFormatter={value => {
      let val = value / 1000000;
           return `$${new Intl.NumberFormat("en").format(val)}m`;
       }}
    />
    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3" vertical={false} />
    <Tooltip />
    <Legend />
    <Line
      dot={false}
      type="monotone"
      dataKey="predictedprice"
      stroke="#1C85E8"
      activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
      name="True Home Estimate™"
      strokeWidth={3}
    />
    <Line
      type="monotone"
      name="Sold Price"
      dataKey="soldprice"
      stroke="#82ca9d"
      shape="star"
     />
</LineChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the shape property to ReferenceDot or ReferenceArea - I'm not sure if the shape properly can be used on regular properties, but here's a link I found to a GitHub conversation that talks more about this:

https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/922